# `<main>': undefined local variable or method `database' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I want to connect MongoDB with Ruby.

I've used the following Ruby file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'

@con = Mongo::Connection.new
@db = @con['tutorial']
@users = @db['users']
```

When I use the command `ruby connect.rb` I get this error:

> undefined local variable or method 'database' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: What mongo driver do you use? The official one uses [`Mongo::Client`](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/quick-start/#make-a-connection) not `Mongo::Connection` to establish the connection.

Comment: Mongo **java** driver?!

Comment: C:\Sites\test_app>ruby connect.rb
D, [2018-02-27T13:30:06.320649 #3184] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Topology type 'unknown' initializing.
D, [2018-02-27T13:30:06.320649 #3184] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Server 127.0.0.1:27017 initializing.
D, [2018-02-27T13:30:06.337667 #3184] DEBUG -- : MONGODB |

Comment: Topology type 'unknown' changed to type 'single'.
D, [2018-02-27T13:30:06.338681 #3184] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Server description for 127.0.0.1:27017 changed from 'unknown' to 'standalone'.
D, [2018-02-27T13:30:06.339713 #3184] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | There was a change in the members of the 'single' topology.
connect.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for #<Mongo::Collection:0x5474628> (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0):

As clearly specified in [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/quick-start/#access-a-database-and-a-collection), the connection should be established that way:

```
@con = Mongo::Client.new('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/tutorial')
@users = @con[:users]
```